# Cannot run app from command line | Can'f find main module in YAPF

Tags: command-line, python, github

I cloned the python code formatter from 
https://github.com/google/yapf.  Now in its documentation (readme file), it states

> Note that if you intend to use YAPF as a command-line tool rather than
>   as a library, installation is not necessary. YAPF supports being run
>   as a directory by the Python interpreter. If you cloned/unzipped YAPF
>   into DIR, it's possible to run:

`$ PYTHONPATH=DIR python DIR/yapf [options] ...`

Now I cloned the project into my home directory. And then I made a test.py file to run the code formatter on this.
I open my terminal and write,

`$ PYTHONPATH=~ python ~/yapf  test.py`

But this fails and gives me the error message as:

`/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in './yapf'`

PS: I had tried this code formatter last week and it ran fine in my terminal. Can somebody please help me here?